# Why exist this $C^2$ function?

Tags: real-analysis, multivariable-calculus, proof-explanation

I am reading the proof of the theorem $1.1$ of this [paper](https://digitalcommons.georgiasouthern.edu/cgi/viewcontent.cgi?article=1328&context=math-sci-facpubs) on page $12$ and I did not understand the existence of the function $d$:

> Since $\partial \Omega$ is $C^2$ smooth, there exists a positive constant $l$ such that $d(\cdot) \in C^2(\overline{\partial \Omega_{3l}})$, and $|\nabla d(\cdot)| \equiv 1$, where $\overline{\partial \Omega_{3l}} := \{ x \in \overline{\Omega} ; d(x) \leq 3l \}$.

I would like to understand it.

Thanks in advance!

Comment: Is $\partial\Omega$ compact? (Guessing "yes".) If so, the intuition is probably to measure oriented distance along the family of normal lines. The directional derivative is $1$ along a normal line. Taking a sufficiently small neighborhood ensures that distinct normal segments are disjoint, so $d$ is well-defined. It's possible to be more specific by modeling the boundary locally as a graph, but the details (which I have not tried to write up) are likely to hide the intuition.

Comment: The paper you are reading is a good example of how **not to** write math paper. You should add many more details to the question. In particular, the domain $\Omega$ is bounded. The function $d$ throughout the paper is the distance function to $cl(\Omega)$. Lastly, the equality $|\nabla d|=1$ is false for general domains, but holds for convex domains.